# Como transformar linhas em colunas, quando o número de linhas é variável em Python

Tags: python

Tenho um data frame que assemelha a tabela plotada abaixo. Os dados são fictícios, mas as colunas são as utilizadas. Os dados foram importados de arquivos csv. Vi uma pergunta semelhante a esta, mas para o R e não Python. Sou novo em Python e não consigo fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso virar as linhas da coluna CD_CONTA gerando novas colunas e preencher com os valores da coluna VL_CONTA e chegar em um resultado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei alguns exemplos, mas não mantém as demais colunas. Alguém pode me ajudar.

Exemplo dos dados hipotéticos plotados na primeira tabela.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'DENOM_CIA': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
'COD_CIA': [101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 101, 101, 101],
'DT_FIM_EXERC': ['31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2021', '31/12/2021', '31/12/2021'],
'CD_CONTA': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
'VL_CONTA': [5, 10, 15, 25, 10, 20, 7, 11, 18]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Comment: Se você tem esses dados disponíveis em suas variáveis, não seria melhor primeiro organiza-los da forma que você precisa e depois criar o DataFrame?

Comment: Os dados foram importados de arquivos csv. O exemplo foi apenas hipotético, mas o cabeçalho e a essência são os mesmos dos dados originais. Vou pesquisar aqui para ver se consigo postar uma amostra dos dados originais.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que esses dados foram importados de um csv e você não tem controle de como o dicionário da variável `d` foi contruído, poderiamos utilizar um defaultdict em que a key represente as informações que não devem ser repetidas (por exemplo, a junção das colunas denom_cia, cod_cia, dt_fim_exerc) e o value é uma lista com os valores representados nas colunas 1, 2 e 3.

Seria algo do tipo:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'DENOM_CIA': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
'COD_CIA': [101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 101, 101, 101],
'DT_FIM_EXERC': ['31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2021', '31/12/2021', '31/12/2021'],
'CD_CONTA': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
'VL_CONTA': [5, 10, 15, 25, 10, 20, 7, 11, 18]
}
# Os dados acima representam dados importados de uma planinha csv

# Organizando os dados antes de criar o DataFrame
quantidade_de_linhas_extraidas = len(d['DENOM_CIA'])  # Obtendo quantidade de linhas através dos valores da coluna DENOM_CIA. Aqui é preciso utilizar uma coluna que sempre possuirá um valor.

linhas_novo_formato = defaultdict(list)

for numero_da_linha in range(quantidade_de_linhas_extraidas):
   DENOM_CIA = d['DENOM_CIA'][numero_da_linha] 
   COD_CIA = d['COD_CIA'][numero_da_linha] 
   DT_FIM_EXERC = d['DT_FIM_EXERC'][numero_da_linha] 
   CD_CONTA = d['CD_CONTA'][numero_da_linha] 
   VL_CONTA = d['VL_CONTA'][numero_da_linha] 

   chave_do_dicionario = (DENOM_CIA, COD_CIA, DT_FIM_EXERC)
   linhas_novo_formato[chave_do_dicionario].append(VL_CONTA)

# Criação do DataFrame
resultado_matriz = []
for chave, valores in linhas_novo_formato.items():
   linha = [*chave, *valores]
   resultado_matriz.append(linha)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=resultado_matriz)
```